# Invalid Credentials. Error authenticating with auth code. Reason: Unable to get local issuer certificate. When authorizing through VS code

Tags: oauth2, authentication, vs-code, invalid

I have been using VS Code and Salesforce since a year in my company laptop.

I am trying to authorize VS code with my sandbox.

Process I followed:

- VS Code> Sfdx auth org shortcut
- Also tried `sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias SFDev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername`

Every time I get below error in browser:

> Error authenticating with auth code due to: request to https://test.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

> This is most likely not an error with the Salesforce CLI. Please ensure all information is accurate and try again.

And below error on VS code:

> ERROR running auth:web:login:  Invalid client credentials. Verify the OAuth client secret and ID. Error authenticating with auth code due to: request to https://test.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/token failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tried some ways like `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0` and Clearing cookies and caches.
or Reinstalling CLI.

Nothing works so far. have been struggling from some time. Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error just now.

I just resolved it by deactivating the company's VPN then re-authorizing via VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, use this command instead:

```
sfdx auth:web:login --setalias SFDev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
```

Note that instead of `force:auth:web:login` I use `auth:web:login`